# google sheets - list (or numbering) depending on content in Columns and rows

Tags: list, google-sheets

in the following sheet i try to number rows depending on the content:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nu8il1f-5sR32hEPGbdHUSRODRbGhFRIV2sMzPv1GvY/edit?usp=sharing

I got 2 sheets. One with the content and one with a query sorted by column A(Kategory), B(SUB Kategory), C(SUB SUB Kategory).

This is the content sheet:

```
**Kategory  SUB Kategory    SUB SUB Kategory**
Fruits      Orange          Italia
Fruits      Apple           New Zealand
Fruits      Cherry          Australia
Vegetables  Tomato          France
Fish        Salmon          Canada
Meat        Pork            Ireland
Fruits      Orange          Israel
Fruits      Apple           Germany
Fish        Salmon          New Zealand
Fish        Makrele         Germany
Vegetables  Tomato          Spain
Vegetables  Cucumber        Germany
```

The goal is to number in the sheet with the query depending on the content as follows:

```
**Kategory  SUB Kategory    SUB SUB Kategory    Numbering #**
Fish        Makrele         Germany             1.1.1
Fish        Salmon          Canada              1.2.1
Fish        Salmon          New Zealand         1.2.2
Fruits      Apple           Germany             2.1.1
Fruits      Apple           New Zealand         2.1.2
Fruits      Cherry          Australia           2.2.1
Fruits      Orange          Israel              2.3.1
Fruits      Orange          Italia              2.3.2
Meat        Pork            Ireland             3.1.1
Vegetables  Cucumber        Germany             4.1.1
Vegetables  Tomato          France              4.2.1
Vegetables  Tomato          Spain               4.2.2
```

The content will grow and the query updates it every time in the numbering sheet. So the numbering  should update it aswell. Similar to a table of contents.

Maybe there is a way to achive this.
thanks jenar

Comment: Hi there @jenargun! This operation could be easily done by [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Would an Apps Script be a valid solution for you?

Comment: Do you want the numbering to appear on your first (unsorted) sheet, or on your second (sorted) sheet? Are all rows unique (as they appear to be from your sample data)?

Comment: @jacques i have no experience with apps script, but if there is no other way, i would try this for sure. It is a big sheet with quite some tabs (sheets). So if there are no Problems in the other tabs, what do i have to do?

Comment: @Tom the numbering should appear in the second sorted sheet. All rows are unique. No Row will appear twice in the sheet, only once with its Kategory, SUB Kategory and SUB SUB Kategorie possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by repeated use of match, first on unique values in column A, then on unique values in A&B combined, then on values in A&B&C combined (because we know that these are already unique):

```
ArrayFormula(if (A2:A="",,match(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A))&
"."&match(A2:A&B2:B,unique(A2:A&B2:B),0)-match(A2:A,index(unique({A2:A,B2:B}),0,1),0)+1&
"."&match(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,0)-match(A2:A&B2:B,A2:A&B2:B,0)+1))
```

[image]

or slightly shorter:

```
=ArrayFormula(if (A2:A="",,match(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A))&
"."&match(A2:A&B2:B,unique(A2:A&B2:B),0)-match(A2:A&"*",unique(A2:A&B2:B),0)+1&
"."&match(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,A2:A&B2:B&C2:C,0)-match(A2:A&B2:B,A2:A&B2:B,0)+1))
```

Comment: ...wow! Thank you Tom. That was the solution! Works like a charme! Now i can bring my learning flash cards in an order and keep track. You are great! Thank you! All the best! jenar